# reborrow &T from &mut T

Tags: rust

```rust
let mut a = String::from("abc");
let b = &mut a;
let c = &*b;
println!("{}", b);
println!("{}", c);
```

The mutable borrow (`&mut T`) is used concurrently with the immutable borrow (`&T`), but it compiles.

It shouldn't compile, and the error should be

```
cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
```

Comment: rust doesn't allow you to have an immutable reference out when you have a mutable reference out. this prevents you from mutating something that another variable believes is immutable

Comment: You're only borrowing `a` in your code once. `c` is borrowed from `b` which is fine since the only other borrow to `b` (the one in `println`) is immutable as well.